# multiple checkbox filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

i am making a filtered array with checkbox inputs. My issue is I can do just filtering by just one of the filtering conditions. when i am trying filter with multiple condition it push duplicate data in foodlists array.

For example if i checked veg and discount i need show only veg and discount products.

```
const data=[
0: {id: 5, name: 'Burger', image: '2021-08-20-611fbe0e334c5.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
1: {id: 6, name: 'Biriyani', image: '2021-08-20-611fbeadbf729.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
2: {id: 15, name: 'Mexican Food', image: '2021-08-20-611fbf96910eb.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
3: {id: 44, name: 'Category name', image: 'image-name', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
4: {id: 45, name: 'cat455', image: '', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
5: {id: 47, name: 'Category One', image: '2022-05-30-62944290134a4.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
6: {id: 49, name: 'what', image: '2022-07-31-62e60949d2e98.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
7: {id: 51, name: 'sdwdwewdewd', image: '2022-08-23-6304b20b5bb0b.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
8: {id: 10, name: 'Chinese', image: '2021-08-20-611fbf1b426e1.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
9: {id: 11, name: 'Fast Food', image: '2021-08-20-611fbf30f1a68.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
10: {id: 37, name: 'Food', image: '2021-12-05-61acb51584a1f.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
11: {id: 39, name: 'Category', image: '2022-05-29-62937a09dec50.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
12: {id: 7, name: 'Asian', image: '2021-08-20-611fbebbc8db2.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
13: {id: 8, name: 'Cake', image: '2021-08-20-611fbecb2b870.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
14: {id: 9, name: 'Coffee & Drinks', image: '2021-08-20-611fbede98fba.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
15: {id: 12, name: 'Kabab & More', image: '2021-08-20-611fbf491f625.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
16: {id: 13, name: 'Indian', image: '2021-08-20-611fbf6a9a159.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
17: {id: 14, name: 'Noodles', image: '2021-08-20-611fbf779aef1.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
18: {id: 16, name: 'Pasta', image: '2021-08-20-611fbfa397c7c.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
19: {id: 17, name: 'Pizza', image: '2021-08-20-611fbfb0af526.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
20: {id: 18, name: 'Snacks', image: '2021-08-20-611fbfbc0e2ed.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
21: {id: 19, name: 'Thai', image: '2021-08-20-611fbfc6ac515.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
22:
created_at: "2021-08-20T14:44:33.000000Z"
id: 20
image: "2021-08-20-611fbfd13f7db.png"
name: "Varieties"
parent_id: 0
position: 0
priority: 0
products: Array(6)
0:
add_ons: []
attributes: []
available_time_ends: "23:57:00"
available_time_starts: "00:01:00"
avg_rating: 0
category_id: 20
category_ids: [{…}]
choice_options: []
created_at: "2021-08-21T11:46:44.000000Z"
description: "Menu Vada is crispy, fluffy, soft, and delicious lentil fritters from South Indian cuisine."
discount: 0
discount_type: "percent"
id: 69
image: "2021-08-21-6120e7a4b7b2a.png"
name: "Medu Vada"
order_count: 7
price: 95
rating_count: 0
recommended: 0
restaurant_closing_time: null
restaurant_discount: 0
restaurant_id: 2
restaurant_name: "Hungry Puppets"
restaurant_opening_time: null
restaurant_status: 1
schedule_order: true
slug: null
status: 1
tags: []
tax: 10
tax_type: "percent"
updated_at: "2023-02-04T09:07:49.000000Z"
variations: []
veg: 0
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {id: 66, name: 'Chicken Shawarma', description: 'Robust and flavorful easy Chicken Shawarma at home…e for Chicken Shawarma adds a bright creamy tang.', image: '2021-08-21-6120e6767300f.png', category_id: 20, …}
2: {id: 62, name: 'Thai Fried Rice', description: 'An authentic recipe for Thai fried rice – just lik…h shrimp/prawns, chicken or any protein you wish.', image: '2021-08-21-6120e5955e1d1.png', category_id: 20, …}
3: {id: 59, name: 'FRIED RICE', description: 'This Chinese-inspired fried rice recipe is my abso… favorite mix-ins, and so irresistibly delicious.', image: '2021-08-21-6120e4dcd5194.png', category_id: 20, …}
4: {id: 58, name: 'Steak Kebabs', description: 'Steak Kebabs are the one of the tastiest summertim…An exciting recipe the whole family can agree on!', image: '2021-08-21-6120e4523fa9d.png', category_id: 20, …}
5: {id: 57, name: 'Steak Kebabs', description: 'Steak Kebabs are the one of the tastiest summertim…An exciting recipe the whole family can agree on!', image: '2021-08-21-6120e44ea58c5.png', category_id: 20, …}
length: 6
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
products_count: 15
slug: null
status: 1
updated_at: "2021-08-20T14:44:33.000000Z"
[[Prototype]]: Object
23: {id: 42, name: 'Catt123', image: '2022-05-30-62943687c9e85.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
24: {id: 56, name: 'Easyy', image: '2023-01-26-63d1f1c767e85.png', parent_id: 0, position: 0, …}
```

]

```
export const filterkey = [
    {
        id:0,
        name:'veg',
        value:"veg",
        isActive:true

    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:'nonVeg',
        value:"nonVeg",
        isActive:false

    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'currentlyAvailable',
        value:"currentlyAvailable",
        isActive:true
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name:'discount',
        value:"discount",
        isActive:false

    },
]


import {isAvailable} from "../../utils/customFunctions";

export const getFilterFood=(data,filterKey)=>{
    console.log("filterKey",filterKey)
    const activeData=filterKey?.filter((item)=>item?.isActive && item)
    let foodLists =[]
        data?.forEach((itemData)=>{
             activeData?.forEach((active)=>{
                 if(active?.value==="nonVeg"){
                     let as=itemData?.products?.filter((food)=>food?.veg===0)
                     foodLists.push({
                         ...itemData,
                         products: as
                     })
                 }
                 if(active?.value==="veg"){
                     let as=itemData?.products?.filter((food)=>food.veg===1)
                     // console.log("foodLists",as)
                     foodLists.push({
                         ...itemData,
                         products: as
                     })

                 }
                 if(active?.value==="currentlyAvailable"){
                     let as=itemData?.products?.filter((food) =>
                                 isAvailable(
                                     food.available_time_starts,
                                     food.available_time_ends
                                 )
                             )
                     foodLists.push({
                         ...itemData,
                         products: as
                     })

                 }
             })
         })
     console.log("foodLists",foodLists)
    return foodLists
}
```

Comment: You do not need to push ```itemData``` in ```foodLists```.

Comment: plz explain more details.

Answer (score 0):

the reasons it make duplicated array it is because you want to push the data element if it check every of your active filterkey but your code for each one of the active filterkey push the food element into the new array if it check the condition.
This is where your problem come from, if a food is both vegan and is available then your code push your food twice in the foodList array because first you push the food to the array since it is vegan and then you push it again into the array since it is available.

I would suggest a more simple, safer and better approach that is using just the **[array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** function with a custom callback to filter your data.
No need to manually push to a new array since the js function duplicate your array.
Also I recommend to add a condition function to your filterKeys object that return a boolean like this:

```
{
    id:1,
    name:'nonVeg',
    value:"nonVeg",
    condition(a) {return a?.veg === 0},
    isActive:false

},
```

Like this you can use the property of your product and pass it as a parameter for each condition function of the active filterkey to verify your food match all of your filters. (you can use the [array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function)

You can make a custom callback function like this:

```
export const multiplesFilterCallback = (food, filterKey) => {
    const activeFilterList = filterKey.filter((filter)=>filter.isActive);

    return activeFilterList.every((filter)=>filter.condition(food[filter.name]);
};
```

Then all you have to do next is to put it as a callback in the filter function for your data:

```
return data.filter(food=>multiplesFilterCallback(food, filterkey));
```

Now, you have a safest, optimized way to filter your food data, additionally you can handle more complex filter thanks to the condition function from each filterkey object.
I hope I was clear in my answer.